# DWG/DXF import in QGis fails

Tags: import, qgis, cad, dxf, dwg

I have a dwg-file and want to import it into QGIS (3.12.3) using Project >> Import DWG/DXF. The import cannot be started with the failure:

`Cannot open layer list`

I converted the dwg in to a dxf using the ODA file converter 21.4.0, but the same error occurs.

After that I tried to import a dwg sample file with the same result, so I guess the file itself is not the problem.

I am new to QGIS - does anyone know why this error occurs?

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in QGis 3.4 that generated this message(1); it should be fixed by now, but it's maybe related to your problem. The problem was in the GeoPackage database: it was impossible to create a new GeoPackage from the interface, you had to select an existing one, but then it didn't have the expected structure.

Do you create a new GeoPackage database or do you provide an existing one?

Just a guess; importing from dwg can fail for several reasons.

(1) https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20305

P.S. I was in fact able to reproduce the error by separatly creating a new GeoPackage and import a dwg in it; the same dwg is imported with no errors when the geopackage is created directly in the importing dialog.